# Google trimming first few words on mobile

Tags: seo, mobile, meta-description

I am seeing a weird problem when searching for our keyword on Google mobile. Instead of trimming the description from end, Google is trimming first four words (it includes Action word) and rest of the description is shown in the search results completely.

I have never seen such behavior in any other search results, except when Google displays the content from the middle of the page to indicate there is text before and after the keyword. Our description length is 148 characters, shows complete on desktop.

Example of how it shows on desktop and mobile below for example keyword "consectetur adipiscing":

**Desktop**: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.

**Mobile**: Mobile-friendly - ... amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.

Comment: Just to confirm, have you searched for "consectetur adipiscing" in this case?

Comment: No, that is just an example.

Comment: Oh I know, just wanted to clarify if the term you had actually searched for was the term that was truncated

Comment: No the term I searched for did not got truncated, it did appeared. It's hard for users to read the description without first few words.

Comment: Got it. Isn't it then just a case of Google trying to pick the most useful description it can, for the search terms you've used? (And for the device too in this case)

Comment: I have never seen this before where Google trims the description from beginning. Also checked other search results having the keyword in the same position as ours, but theirs got trimmed from end as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this was because of Google experimenting something. Today when searching with the same keyword Google displays the description as expected, everything shown from beginning and trimming last few words. We did not changed anything during this entire time on the website so it was definitely from Google's end.

Thank you for your help.